# React: trying to get an average number from data fetched from db

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, average, react-component, react-functional-component

I am trying to make a react component that returns the average number after fetching the data from the DB and converting it to json.

Total novice here. I am trying to make a react component that returns the average number after fetching the data from the DB and converting it to json. This is the json I am working with, which is fetched succesfully, but I am not sure how to do the calculation in react. Basically I am trying to get the average from all the numbers in the field "ivertinimai".[image]

This is the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef }  from 'react';

const AverageEvaluation = (props) => {
let [allEvaluations, setAllEvaluations] = useState()
let [evaluationsArray, setEvaluationsArray] = useState([])
let [sum, setSum] = useState(0)
let [average, setAverage] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getevaluations/" + props.mealId, {method: 'GET', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response=>{setAllEvaluations(allEvaluations=response); console.log(response)})
}, []);

let getAverage = () => {
    allEvaluations.map((meal, index)=>setEvaluationsArray([...evaluationsArray, meal.ivertinimai]))
    setSum(evaluationsArray.reduce((a,v) =>  a = a + v, 0 ))
    setAverage(average = sum/evaluationsArray.length)
}

return (
    <>
        {average}
    </>
);
```

};

The component doesn't seem to return any result after I import and add it in another component. I'm not sure if the problem is in the function to calculate the average or is it that I am trying to use react in the wrong way here. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I see that need a change:

1. It should be `const [ ..., ... ] = ...` not `let [..., ...]`
2. I would put an empty array into initial declaration of `allEvaluations` -> `useState([]);`
3. `setAllEvaluations(allEvaluations=response)` and `setAverage(average = sum/evaluationsArray.length)` should be `setAllEvaluations(response)` and setAverage(sum/evaluationsArray.length)`

Variables `allEvaluations` and `average` should not be changed, so writing `avegare = ...` is not only incorrect but also if written in set functions will not result in changing their values. That's because you are not putting there a new value but an assignment to a variable.

Similarly in `reduce((a,v) =>  a = a + v, 0 )`, just write `reduce((a,v) =>  a + v, 0 )` - no assignment needed.

4. Your `getAverage` function.

Firstly, instead of

```
allEvaluations.map((meal, index)=>setEvaluationsArray([...evaluationsArray, meal.ivertinimai]));
setSum(evaluationsArray.reduce((a,v) =>  a = a + v, 0 ));
setAverage(average = sum/evaluationsArray.length);
```

try something like this:

```
const newEvaluationsArray = allEvaluations.map((meal) => meal.ivertinimai);
setEvaluationsArray(newEvaluationsArray);
const newSum = newEvaluationsArray.reduce((a,v) =>  a + v, 0 );
setSum(newSum);
setaverage(newSum/newEvaluationsArray.length);
```

In the map function you wrote, you needlessly call `setEvaluationsArray` for each meal object and needlessly create new and new arrays (`[...evaluationsArray, meal.ivertinimai]`).

Then in your `setSum` and `setAverage`, you are using the useState variable `(evaluationsArray)` which you have just modified. I would not recommend doing this, as when I did it sometimes there was still the old value, not the just updated one. (I'm not sure about the inner workings of useState and why/when is it happening, but I prefer to be cautious).
The same applies for `sum` and `setAverage`.

In my code, I first map `allEvaluations` and then assign them to a constant. This creates just one new array instead of multiple. This also makes it so that you can both set the new value in `setEvaluationsArray` and be sure in `setSum` that it is the new value you wanted. I did a similar thing with `newSum`.

Secondly, you aren't calling your `getAverage` function anywhere. There are multiple options for you. Probably the easiest option is to put it in `useEffect` after `setAllEvaluations(response);` You will have to change `getAverage` function to accept arguments, for the same reason we made `newEvaluationsArray` and `newSum` above:

```
const getAverage = (response) => {      
  const newEvaluationsArray = response.map((meal) => meal.ivertinimai);
  setEvaluationsArray(newEvaluationsArray);
  const newSum = newEvaluationsArray.reduce((a,v) =>  a + v, 0 );
  setSum(newSum);
  setaverage(newSum/newEvaluationsArray.length);  
}
```

At this point, you could just rewrite the body of `getAverage` into the `useEffect` and remove `getAverage`, if this is the only place where you will call it.

Hope it helps, good luck!